# Request python 3.7 (ERROR WinError 10060)

Tags: python-3.7

Estoy intentando descargar el contenido web de la web https://es.gearbest.com/gadget-deals.html

con cualquier otra web funciona, pero con esta no.
he leído algo sobre las cabeceras, pero he probado varias y nada.

```python
from urllib import request
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
import re

#headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 GTB7.1 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)", "Referer": "http://example.com"}

url = 'https://es.gearbest.com/gadget-deals.html'
page = urlopen(Request(url, headers=headers, )).read()#.decode('utf8')
#page = urlopen(Request(url)).read()

print(page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa página parece ser bastante exigente con lo que el cliente le envía (quizás para evitar que le hagas *scraping*). No he conseguido que me responda usando la biblioteca `urllib` que tú usas, pero sí usando `requests`, y con un `User-Agent` adecuado (el que tú pones en tu código tampoco lo admitía).

Este es el código que me funcionó:

```
import requests

headers = {
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
}

url = "https://es.gearbest.com/gadget-deals.html"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(r.status_code)
```

---

```
200
```

Si algo no está como espera, el servidor simplemente no responde, causando un *timeout* en el cliente (que es el error 10060 que obtienes)

Comment: Muchas Gracias!, funcionó con requests, es la única web de las que probé hasta ahora que no funciona jaja, un saludo.